# How to add an AAR file in Android Studio so it is recognised by the GUI

Tags: android-studio

I have followed the instructions here to add a reference to an AAR but the file is not recognised by Android Studio and is not committed in my VCS.

http://geekgarage.dad3zero.net/local-aar-android-library/

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html

Should I manually add it to my git repository or is there a better way to add the `libs` folder in the Android Studio project.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, and since its old, its probably referencing an old version of Android Studio.

For Android Studio 1.5:

- File -> New -> New Module...
- Select "Import .JAR/.AAR Package"
- Hit F4 (Open Module Settings)
- Select your app in left pan
- Select "Dependencies" tab
- Click +, New Module Dependency
- Select the package name for the AAR you imported.

That should do it.